# pecl install mongodb ERROR: failed to mkdir

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, pecl

I was trying to install mongodb driver for PHP on macOS Monterey v 12 on m1 chip.

running command below gives me error

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

already tried various solutions, didnt help me

here is what is shown in terminal

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/pecl/20190902/mongodb.so'

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/share/php@7.4/pear/System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): Not a directory in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/share/php@7.4/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/pecl/20190902
```

here whats in folder the error refers

```
user*****@Mac-mini 7.4.26_1 % cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/                  
user*****@Mac-mini 7.4.26_1 % ls -la
total 256
drwxr-xr-x  16 user*****  admin     512 Jan 12 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 user*****  admin      96 Dec  1 12:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 user*****  admin     128 Nov 16 21:31 .bottle
drwxr-xr-x   3 user*****  admin      96 Nov 16 21:31 .brew
-rw-r--r--   1 user*****  admin    5800 Dec  1 12:09 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--   1 user*****  admin    3204 Nov 16 21:31 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 user*****  admin  100181 Nov 16 21:31 NEWS
-rw-r--r--   1 user*****  admin    4712 Nov 16 21:31 README.md
drwxr-xr-t  12 root       admin     384 Dec  1 12:08 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 user*****  admin     594 Dec  1 12:08 homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 user*****  admin     283 Dec  1 12:08 homebrew.php@7.4.service
drwxr-xr-x   3 user*****  admin      96 Nov 16 21:31 include
drwxr-xr-x   4 user*****  admin     128 Nov 16 21:31 lib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user*****  admin      46 Jan 12 16:30 pecl -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/bin/pecl
drwxr-xr-t   3 root       admin      96 Dec  1 12:08 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   5 user*****  admin     160 Nov 16 21:31 share
user*****@Mac-mini 7.4.26_1 %
```

tried to fix that symlink @pecl, did not work

please help

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue, the problems was with symlinks... found the right folder and edited symlink to redirect to this folder.
by default pecl installer was trying to mkdir in path

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/pecl
```

this is symlink, and it was pointing to executable file in .../bin/pecl
So I edited this symlink to point to another suitable folder, this may be different for your installation. Folder called *pecl*, in: `homebrew/lib/php/`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.26_1/bin/pecl
```

Then run install again